# How to display specific record of the logged in user?(MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I wish to create a profile page that will display the users personal record and im using ASP.NET MVC 4>internet application. For example i have a table UserProfile

```
UserID   UserName   Name   Age   Gender                                             

1          john     John    17     Male

2          dave     Dave    15     Male

3          mark     Mark    20     Male
```

then if i log-in using the UserName john, all the information of the username john will be only displayed in the profile page

*sorry i find it hard to explain

```
public class HomeController : Controller     //HomeController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        return View();
    }
public ActionResult Contact()
    {

        return View();
    }
}






public class UsersContext : DbContext    // AccountModel
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: query the table and get the record and pass it to view using a view model.

Answer (score 0):

Get your username

```
 string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
```

Then

```
var record=from c in db.tablename where UserName   = username select c
```